# how to convert stringWithUTF8String to swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, string

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:data.bytes];
    NSLog(@"%@",str);
}
```

Please convert this objective c function in swift

Comment: Did you look at [delegate reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate/connection:didReceiveData:)? Did you read this perfect [Obj-C in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html) manual?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Tell us what you tried and what is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will look like

```
func connectDataReceived(connection: NSURLConnection, data: NSData){
    let str = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    print(str)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I post the answer which is very easiest way and you can understand easily.

```
let strData = "A384CVHJLWHBWRLBRH2348945607275epiuthgthgbpbfvrvdiac15szerqTUDGA89ty757909577257908hbdshjkbhvalasdhbchdcvgcvjvgvaKLOYAQCGHQ"
let data = strData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!
let str = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
print("\(str)")
```